# Dagger skips Factory generation for Google Services module when using kapt

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, kotlin, dagger-2

I have an Android app that I've been converting to Kotlin, and I've run into a roadblock with Dagger when it comes to a particular module.

In my project `build.gradle`, I have:

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = "1.0.1-2"

  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha5'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-rc3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And in `app/build.gradle`, I have the following relevant setup:

```
apply plugin: "nebula.dependency-lock"
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: "kotlin-android-extensions"
apply plugin: "com.getkeepsafe.dexcount"

// ...

android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

  // ...

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    // ...
  }

  buildTypes {
    debug {
      applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
      // ...
    }

    release {
      // ...
    }
  }

  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }

  sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    debug.java.srcDirs += 'src/debug/kotlin'
    release.java.srcDirs += 'src/release/kotlin'
    androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTest/kotlin'
    test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
  }
}

kapt {
  generateStubs = true
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ["*.jar"], dir: "libs")

  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$playServicesVersion"
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$playServicesVersion"

  compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
  kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
}

buildscript {
  ext.daggerVersion = "2.2"
  ext.playServicesVersion = "8.4.0"

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.netflix.nebula:gradle-dependency-lock-plugin:4.2.0'
    classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.4.4'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
  }

  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  jcenter()
  maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
}

apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

I have an application component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = arrayOf(
                DebugApplicationModule::class,
                DataModule::class,
                DebugApiModule::class,
                GoogleApiModule::class,
                DebugSystemServicesModule::class
        )
)
interface ApplicationComponent : DebugApplicationGraph
```

And the `GoogleApiModule`:

```
@Module
@Singleton
class GoogleApiModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideGoogleApiAvailability(): GoogleApiAvailability {
        return GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideGcmRegistrationManager(
            context: Context,
            preferences: AppPreferences,
            googleApiAvailability: GoogleApiAvailability,
            apiService: ApiService): GCMRegistrationManager {

        return GCMRegistrationManager(context, preferences, googleApiAvailability, apiService)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideGoogleAnalytics(context: Context): GoogleAnalytics {
        val analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context)
        analytics.setDryRun(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        return analytics
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAnalyticsTracker(analytics: GoogleAnalytics): Tracker {
        val tracker = analytics.newTracker(BuildConfig.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID)
        tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true)
        tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true)
        return tracker
    }
}
```

When I build the application, I get the following errors coming from the generated `DaggerApplicationComponent, saying it can't find the symbols for these classes:

[image: DaggerApplicationComponent]

There don't appear to be any other errors in any of my other modules (there are plenty), and all the other modules in `main` for that component appear to work as well.

What I don't understand is what would be causing this to fail building the factories for this module, but not others, and why it's failing so silently. Same structure builds fine in the Java version of the application.

I've tried using `provided` instead of `kapt` for `dagger-compiler`, but that seems to skip dagger compilation entirely.

I've tried any number of configuration changes to get this working but I always get the same results.

Sometimes, but not always, I'll also get this message printed before the errors:

```
Note: Generating a MembersInjector for com.myapp.services.GCMMessageListenerService. 
Prefer to run the dagger processor over that class instead.
```

I'm not sure what that means, and I'm not sure if it's related to the missing compilations, nor do I know how to fix it if it was.

Comment: You have `kapt` configuration setup correctly. You are using the latest dagger 2 and kotlin versions correctly. I do not think you should compile with JDK8 unless you are using the Jack compiler or retrolambda. Also, it looks like you are missing `provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'`, see here https://github.com/damianpetla/kotlin-dagger-example/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L55.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. After attempting to split out the different parts of the `GoogleApiModule` into different modules, a different module was getting skipped, so I looked into it and found that two different modules had methods named the same, but returning different types and accepting different arguments. Changing the names so they wouldn't clash fixed the issue.

Edit:

I had another module that provided an application Analytics Tracker that relied on the Google Analytics Tracker. The two different modules both had a method called `provideAnalyticsTracker`. They had different method signatures and return types, but kapt had a problem compiling it, despite not reporting any meaningful errors. Apt with Java could handle the naming collision.

Comment: Can you please post a code example to go a long with your question and mark this correct if this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

## Correct:

- You have `kapt` configuration setup correctly
- You are using the latest Dagger 2 and Kotlin versions correctly.

## Things to look at:

- I do not think you should compile with JDK8 unless you are using the Jack compiler or Retrolambda.
- It looks like you are missing `provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'`, see here https://github.com/damianpetla/kotlin-dagger-example/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L55.

Comment: Downgraded to use JDK7, which did highlight an spot I missed since getting rid of retrolambda, but that didn't change anything. Added glassfish in just to test things out and that doesn't help either. As of Dagger 2.1, it's no longer required: https://github.com/google/dagger/commit/0488c9d339031eacaa8eda39e761930e4532c259

Comment: I have this kotlin + dagger working in a project of mine. Can you push yours to github?

Comment: Private repo, so I can't push it to you, sorry. The weird thing is it works for all the other modules, but only this one is broken.